# Submitting apps to App Store using individual account representing a group

Tags: ios, app-store

Is it possible to submit apps to Apple's App Store using an individual account, if the app was developed by a group of people? (we are a group of 4, created the app but we don't have a company, we just agreed to submit it, even if it stays at the name of only one of us at the store)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes of course, have a look [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/8003/how-to-submit-your-app-to-apple-from-no-account-to-app-store-part-1) for example.

You need to chose an individual App Developer Account for you 4.

Comment: Thanks!
I tried to find that info on Apple Developer's website, to no avail.

Comment: ;) Do not hesitate to valid the answer if it's helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

Technically speaking yes, but keep in mind you probably should have some in writing agreement about the application. Basically your funds will be deposited into the account of the person who is on the Apple Developers Account, electronically.

Good luck on your new venture!